# Locked/crossed prices in US equities

Tags: equities, market-data, limit-order-book, orderbook, feed

I'm trying to build a consolidated LOB from several direct feeds.

However, there are many instances in which for a given stock, the bid price in one venue equals or crosses the ask price in a different venue.

Is that a valid state or do I have an issue with out-of-order event processing across the different feeds? In such case, what's the best way to "fix" the LOB back to a valid state (e.g. ignore the locking/crossing event, remove the locked/crossed prices)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to observe it due to the latency between different exchange locations. You may try to fall back on SIP if it persists for more than a few seconds, though probably that part should be outside of your LOB construction.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you want to rebuild the book venue by venue. NBBO is a different story.